# Fast Extended Euclidean Algorithm in Harley's elliptic curves point counting method

Tags: elliptic-curves

Could you help me with Harley's norm computation algorithm that is based on the Fast Extended Euclidean Algorithm that was suggested by Harley in an email to NMBRTHRY list in 2002 and that described in Vercauteren's thesis pp 87-90:

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c945/c98267db064b272c87a885fc5eeb764b0b2d.pdf

[image]
[image]

My implementation working correctly and fast for low degree polynomials without modulo and for high degree polynomials with modulo M, where M is a prime number greater than 2^N.
But all I need - it's a resultant modulo 2^N (or 2^(N*c) due to Vercauteren's Remark 3.10.3) of two large polynomials. So I should include in routine mod 2^N (or mod 2^(N*c)...) instructions to avoid exponential coefficients' growing.
But since the 2^N is not prime it's a problem - polynomials contain even coefficients and this leads to some even denominators - and for example multiplicative inverse 1/2 mod 2^N doesn't exist.
Please tell me how to solve this problem?

How to adapt XCGD routine for correct mod 2^N calculation of resultant (norm)?

Thank you.

Best regards,
Vadim

Comment: Please refrain yourself from [cross-posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3770106/338051). This is considered not ethical in SO networks. [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/403350). Please keep one question alive.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because crossposted with Math.SE

Comment: Any ideas about the question?

Comment: I am not familiar with your question, but i had a quick look at this algorithm. As far as I can tell all the computations are in the field $K$ (I can't see where is this ${\rm mod}{2^N}$ you wrote about). For the resultant the author suggests Lemma 3.10.2

Comment: @111
> I can't see where is this mod2N you wrote about
Of course. It's a question how to insert mod in XGCD.

> For the resultant the author suggests Lemma 3.10.2
Algorithm 3.10.6 follows from this lemma

Comment: Are you sure that the algorithm is still valid after $\mod{2^N}?$ You can't just take a modulo and to expect the thinngs works as previous. Right? For instance, Lemma 3.10.2 demands the polynomial have coefficients to a field ${\mathcal{K}}$ but when you are working at $({\bf Z}/\langle 2^N )\rangle[X]$ this ring does not have the same properties as ${\mathcal{K}}[X].$ So maybe you have to proof similar theorems as in phd thesis but for the commutative ring ${\bf Z}/\langle 2^N \rangle[X]$ Also I agree that this question has nothing to do with crypto.

Comment: Algorithm is vaild for mod p, where p - prime number larger than largest cooefficient of polynomials. I could just insert "mod p" in lines of XGCD that contain ariphmetic operations with polynomails and get correct resultant mod p. As Vercauteren says this algorithm should work also for mod 2^N (precisely mod 2^(N*c)). But the way to adapt XGCD in this case not so trivial.

Comment: This algorithm is a part of Harley's scheme of elliptic curves point counting - important part of elliptic curves open-key cryptography